# PostgreSQL 9.6 - psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

Linux Mint 2**0.2**, Postgresql **9.6** on local host

in file *var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data_hba.conf*

```
  # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all            0.0.0.0/0                trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

In terminal I run command:

```
sudo systemctl status  postgresql
```

And here result:

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-08-04 14:44:45 EEST; 18min ago
    Process: 89155 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 89155 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 04 14:44:45 alex systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Aug 04 14:44:45 alex systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Nice.
But when I run my application to connect to local PostgreSQL I get error:

```
2021-08-04 15:04:55.929 INFO  [check_db_status:140865] Checking DB status
2021-08-04 15:04:55.934 INFO  [check_db_status:140865] ip: 127.0.0.1, port: 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2021-08-04 15:04:55.961 INFO  [check_db_status:140865] Waiting (retry number 1 out of 36) for DB to come up
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2021-08-04 15:05:00.992 INFO  [check_db_status:140865] Waiting (retry number 2 out of 36) for DB to come up
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2021-08-04 15:05:06.024 INFO  [check_db_status:140865] Waiting (retry number 3 out of 36) for DB to come up
```

In file `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf` has

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I try this:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

Result is:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file
```

here content of `var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log`

```
2021-08-05 14:59:14.739 EEST [116538] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 14:59:13 EEST
2021-08-05 14:59:14.741 EEST [116538] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-08-05 14:59:14.746 EEST [116537] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05 14:59:14.746 EEST [116542] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-08-05 14:59:15.210 EEST [116544] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2021-08-05 14:59:55.996 EEST [116537] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-08-05 14:59:55.996 EEST [116537] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-08-05 14:59:55.997 EEST [116542] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2021-08-05 14:59:55.998 EEST [116539] LOG:  shutting down
2021-08-05 14:59:56.037 EEST [116537] LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-08-05 14:59:57.069 EEST [119294] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 14:59:56 EEST
2021-08-05 14:59:57.072 EEST [119294] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-08-05 14:59:57.073 EEST [119299] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-08-05 14:59:57.073 EEST [119290] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05 14:59:57.549 EEST [119301] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2021-08-05 15:03:46.004 EEST [119290] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-08-05 15:03:46.004 EEST [119290] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-08-05 15:03:46.004 EEST [119299] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2021-08-05 15:03:46.005 EEST [119296] LOG:  shutting down
2021-08-05 15:03:46.018 EEST [119290] LOG:  database system is shut down
2021-08-05 15:03:47.070 EEST [119631] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-08-05 15:03:46 EEST
2021-08-05 15:03:47.072 EEST [119631] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2021-08-05 15:03:47.074 EEST [119630] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-08-05 15:03:47.074 EEST [119639] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2021-08-05 15:03:47.557 EEST [119642] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

also this command:

```
pg_lsclusters

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

Comment: have you restarted the database after changing the `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: @JimJones i use this  "sudo service postgresql restart" , but it not help. Same error

Comment: Does the log file give you any hints?

Comment: @JimJones Where I can see this log?

Comment: in my ubuntu the log files can be found at: `/var/log/postgresql/`

Comment: @JimJones In my host this folder is empty

Comment: @JimJones Tried, but it not help. Same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235623/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-a-subscriber).

Comment: @JimJones I was updated my post with log

Comment: The error message suggests that postgres wasn't properly installed (misssing packages). Try purging it and install it again (or solve the missing dependencies manually) :|